# How to make column values to others column values

Tags: mysql

I have a table shown like below.

```
Region  Market      Cluster     Dt1-Accept  Dt2-Accept  Dt3-Accept  
South   Karnataka   Bangalore   21-06-2014  24-07-2015  25-08-2016
South   Karnataka   Belgaum     21-06-2014  24-07-2015  25-08-2016
```

I want to show it using sql

```
Region  Market      cluster     Dt1-Accept
South   Karnataka   Bangalore   21-06-2014
South   Karnataka   Belgaum     21-06-2014
South   Karnataka   Bangalore   24-07-2015
South   Karnataka   Belgaum     24-07-2015
South   Karnataka   Bangalore   25-08-2016
South   Karnataka   Belgaum     25-08-2016
```

Please help

Comment: union should  make it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a software writing service... this question will be closed in due course. You should to [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and show what has been done so far to solve it

Answer (score 3):

```
select Region, Market, Cluster, Dt1-Accept from "table"
union all
(select Region, Market, Cluster, Dt2-Accept from "table")
union all
(select Region, Market, Cluster, Dt3-Accept from "table")
```